# Using base class typedef in derived class

Tags: c++

I try to use a base class typedef in derived class as a return type.

```
template <typename T>
class Base{
public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    virtual size_type size() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
    using typename Base<T>::size_type;
    virtual size_type size();
};

template <typename T>
typename Derived<T>::size_type Derived<T>::size() {
    return 1;
}
```

clang can compile the code while msvc cannot. The compiler said "the definition of size does not match its declaration".

I modify the code:

```
template <typename T>
typename Base<T>::size_type Derived<T>::size() {
    return 1;
}
```

The situation is opposite.

I think `typename Base<T>::size_type` makes more sense since the virtual function declared in base class also uses base class typedef. But clang dose not allow.

How do I modify the code to make it compiled by both compilers if I have to use **out-of-class** definition?

Comment: What compiler version? I have VS2017 and it compiles the code without problem.

Comment: @BoPersson Also VS2017. I got error C2244.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking if Clang (and GCC, btw) accepts your code while MSVC doesn't, it's usually not a sign that something is wrong with your code. MSVC's implementation of templates has been non-compliant for a long time.

However, recognizing that we live in the real world and have to content with less than optimal tools, you are gonna have to just get rid of the using declaration. This modified code will be accepted on both compilers:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
class Base{
public:
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    virtual size_type size() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
    virtual typename Base<T>::size_type size();
};

template <typename T>
typename Base<T>::size_type Derived<T>::size() {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I found that `using size_type = typename Base<T>::size_type;` solved the ambiguous problem.